# Propel saving tags

Tags: propel

I have a Post model and I am inserting the Tags for the posts like the one below. When I am editing there can be some tags being removed. So what is the right way to remove the tags and re-insert ?

```
$post->setTitle($data['title']);
$post->setBody($data['body']);
$post->setSlug($data['slug']);
$tags = explode(',', $data['tags']);
// Want to remove the tags
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tagobj = TagQuery::create()->findOneByName($tag);
    if (! $tagobj) {
         $tagobj = new Tag();
         $tagobj->setName($tag);
         $tagobj->save();
    }
    $post->addTag($tagobj);
}
$post->save();
```

Does propel can insert in a single query or is this a worst approach .

I have asked the question in propel group, but :-( https://groups.google.com/d/msg/propel-users/x6PH_DwLtVE/H84o1cu4W4kJ

The full source code is [here](https://github.com/harikt/Hari.Sample)

The goal is to re-save the tags, when one tag is removed or one tag is added. What to do ? .

1st priority.

Optimization is second priority.

Update2 :

I modified the code as something like below with the reply I got

```
$tags = explode(',', $data['tags']);
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tagobj = TagQuery::create()->findOneByName($tag);
    if (! $tagobj) {
        $tagobj = new Tag();
        $tagobj->setName($tag);
        $tagobj->save();
    }
}
// var_dump($tags);
$tagcollection = TagQuery::create()->findByName($tags);
// var_dump($tagcollection);
// exit;
$post->setTags($tagcollection);
```

Now I am getting array to string conversion error .

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/harisample/vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Runtime/Connection/StatementWrapper.php on 
line 171 Call Stack: 0.0001 131940 

 {main}() /var/www/harisample/web/index.php:0 0.0243 1259056 

 Aura\Framework\Bootstrap\Web->exec() /var/www/harisample/web/index.php:13 0.0243 1259108 

 Aura\Framework\Web\Controller\Front->exec() /var/www/harisample/package/Aura.Framework/src/Aura/Framework/Bootstrap/Web.php:71 0.0243 1259436 

 Aura\Framework\Web\Controller\Front->request() /var/www/harisample/package/Aura.Framework/src/Aura/Framework/Web/Controller/Front.php:168 0.0314 1694584 

 Aura\Web\Controller\AbstractPage->exec() /var/www/harisample/package/Aura.Framework/src/Aura/Framework/Web/Controller/Front.php:222 0.0316 1699500 
Aura\Web\Controller\AbstractPage->action() /var/www/harisample/package/Aura.Web/src/Aura/Web/Controller/AbstractPage.php:168 0.0316 1699576 
Aura\Web\Controller\AbstractPage->invokeMethod() /var/www/harisample/package/Aura.Web/src/Aura/Web/Controller/AbstractPage.php:206 0.0316 1699960 
ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /var/www/harisample/package/Aura.Web/src/Aura/Web/Controller/AbstractPage.php:231 0.0316 1699976 
 Hari\Sample\Web\Post\Page->actionEdit() /var/www/harisample/package/Aura.Web/src/Aura/Web/Controller/AbstractPage.php:231 0.0856 5802116 1
 Hari\Sample\Model\Base\Post->save() /var/www/harisample/package/Hari.Sample/src/Hari/Sample/Web/Post/Page.php:127 0.0874 5808356 1
 Hari\Sample\Model\Base\Post->doSave() /var/www/harisample/package/Hari.Sample/src/Hari/Sample/Model/Base/Post.php:930 0.0881 5813420 1
 Hari\Sample\Model\Base\PostTagQuery->delete() /var/www/harisample/package/Hari.Sample/src/Hari/Sample/Model/Base/Post.php:1000 0.0881 5813700 1
 Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\ModelCriteria->delete() /var/www/harisample/package/Hari.Sample/src/Hari/Sample/Model/Base/PostTagQuery.php:557 0.0881 5814628 1
 Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria->doDelete() /var/www/harisample/vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Runtime/ActiveQuery/ModelCriteria.php:1324 0.0883 5817716 1
 Propel\Runtime\Connection\StatementWrapper->execute() /var/www/harisample/vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Runtime/ActiveQuery/Criteria.php:2408 0.0883 5817772 1
 PDOStatement->execute() /var/www/harisample/vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Runtime/Connection/StatementWrapper.php:171
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess your goal is optimizing the number of (mysql ?) request, isn't it ?

I think this is not possible, mainly because Propel object saving rely on other steps  - think of preSave(), postSave(), behaviors also - needing a single saving query execution for every object.

By trying to make an optimized query, you would loose the benefit of the Propel saving workflow and relations management.

On the other hand, I am not sure about the way `clearTags()` really works, I think it just remove object references but does not delete records in the database.

You must have in your BasePost.php file a `setTags()` method that will actually replace any previous relation with the new object collection you provide.

Comment: The goal is not optimizing. The goal is to re-save tags. I will check the `setTags`. Thanks

Comment: `setTags` doesn't worked. See the run time error updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making sth similar, but still something is not good. Maybe you can try, maybe it will work on your project.

```
$tagNames = $tags->getTags();
$tagsArray = explode(',', $tagNames);

$postTagToDelete = PostTagQuery::create()->filterByPostId($post->getId())->find();
if ($postTagToDelete) {
    $postTagToDelete->delete();
}

foreach ($tagsArray as $tagName) {
    $tag = TagQuery::create()->filterByName($tagName)->findOne();
    //when i find an existing tag,
    // there is no need to create another one
    //I just simply add it **(it's not working here)**
    if ($tag != null) {
        $post->addTag($tag);

    } else {
        //when tag is new
        $tag = new Tag();
        $tag->setName($tagName);


        $post->addTag($tag);

    }
}
$post->save()
```

See [my problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376335/propel-save-object-error-tags).

To be more specific, let's pretend that I have four elements in `$tagsArray`.

```
[first, second, third, fourth]
```

Every of them IS the database already, so it gonna enter first if four times.

The problem is that only second, third and fourth will be saved. There will be no first . Why?

Another example is that if I have array[first] and do the same (first is in the databse already) it will be saved every only the second time. So I have sth like is in database, database empty, is in database, database empty,[...] every request attempt.