# Propel Save Object Error Tags

Tags: mysql, symfony, object, propel

I have problem with my little part of code. Symfony2, PROPEL ORM.

```
    $tagNames = $tags->getTags();
    $tagsArray = explode(',', $tagNames);

    $postTagToDelete = PostTagQuery::create()->filterByPostId($post->getId())->find();
    if ($postTagToDelete) {
        $postTagToDelete->delete();
    }

    foreach ($tagsArray as $tagName) {
        $tag = TagQuery::create()->filterByName($tagName)->findOne();
        //when i find an existing tag,
        // there is no need to create another one
        //I just simply add it **(it's not working here)**
        if ($tag != null) {
            $post->addTag($tag);

        } else {
            //when tag is new
            $tag = new Tag();
            $tag->setName($tagName);


            $post->addTag($tag);

        }
    }
```

Everytime I'm creating new objects of PostTags. I clean the main object of PostTag and then create a new ones.

Problem is that, it always does not saving the first tag I have in my $tagNames.

To be more specific, let's pretend that I have four elements in `$tagsArray`.

`[first, second, third, fourth]`

Every of them IS the database already, so it gonna enter first `if` four times.

The problem is that only `second`, `third` and `fourth` will be saved. There will be no `first` . Why?

Another example is that if I have `array[first]` and do the same (`first` is in the databse already) it will be saved every only the second time.
So I have sth like `is in database, database empty, is in database, database empty,[...]` every request attempt.

Any suggestions?

Thank you, I really need that.

Thx,
D

After all I found solution which works like a charm.

```
    $tagNames = $tags->getTags();
    $tagsArray = explode(',', $tagNames);
    $tagsArray = array_unique($tagsArray);

    $tagManager = $this->container->get('back_tag.manager');
    $tags = new PropelOwnCollection();
    foreach ($tagsArray as $tag) {
        if (is_numeric($tag)) { //naprawa bledu pluginu select2
            $tags->append($tagManager->findOneOrCreateById($tag));
        } else if (!empty($tag)) {
            $tags->append($tagManager->findOneOrCreateByName($tag));
        }
    }
    $post->setTags($tags);
    $post->save();
```

Comment: You mean there's no row in PostTag table for the relation `first` => `post`? What returns $posts->getTags() after the foreach?

Comment: Well, this described problem wasn't been solved, but I found another solution for that, which works like a charm. Thank you.